# Initializing nested object in `useState` object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have a couple of API returns that may or may not return certain values, I am effectively setting all other values *except* the `primaryInfo.address` values. I **can** log these nested values individually. Meaning if there *is* a value in the API return it *will* log the value, *if not* it *will* return an empty string. I have tried hard coding the nested values as well to no avail, it seems like more of a `setState` on a nest object issue than the operators that set them, but if I was sure I wouldn't be here

```js
  const [primaryInfo, setPrimaryInfo] = useState({
    first_name:
      finance_info?.primary_borrower?.first_name ||
      primary_contact_ref?.first_name ||
      "",
    last_name:
      finance_info?.primary_borrower?.last_name ||
      primary_contact_ref?.last_name ||
      "",
    email:
      finance_info?.primary_borrower?.email ||
      primary_contact_ref?.email_one ||
      "",
    phone:
      finance_info?.primary_borrower?.phone ||
      primary_contact_ref?.phone_cell ||
      "",
    resides_in_home: finance_info?.primary_borrower?.resides_in_home ?? true,
    address: finance_info?.primary_borrower?.resides_in_home
      ? { ...addressInfo }
      : {
          street_one: finance_info?.primary_borrower?.address?.street_one || "",
          street_two: finance_info?.primary_borrower?.address?.street_two || "",
          city: finance_info?.primary_borrower?.address?.city || "",
          state: finance_info?.primary_borrower?.address?.street_one || "",
          zip: finance_info?.primary_borrower?.address?.street_one || "",
        },
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

My reccomendation is do all this in the useEffect hook and pass your props down as dependencies.

```
 const [primaryInfo, setPrimaryInfo] = useState(undefined)

useEffect(() => {
// add all your logic here
const object = {}
if(finance_info?.primary_borrower?.first_name) object.firstName = finance_info.primary_borrower.first_name;
// .
// .
// .
// and so on.
   setPrimaryInfo(object); 
}, [finance_info])


if(!primaryInfo) return <div> Loading... </div>
```

Comment: I was building out a version of your idea because initializing the WHOLE state in a `useEffect`, because of synchronous reasons, was breaking a ton of stuff lol. I was going to initialize the parent object then `useEffect` the address in after-the-fact. But then I saw my error  I was overwriting the incoming address with a separate `useEffect` I had as a switch to empty or populate depending on the user selection. Great idea though! I was going through with it and saw my own mistake.